# GObject override signal in GTK+

Tags: python-3.x, gtk3, pygobject, gobject

I thought I would try updating a program I found on the web ([Signals & events in PyGTK](http://zetcode.com/gui/pygtk/signals/)) illustrating how to override a signal in a subclass. Here is my version:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject

class PyApp(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)

        self.set_size_request(200, 150)
        self.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)
        self.show_all()

        self.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)

    @GObject.SignalOverride
    def configure_event(self, *args):
        pass

    def do_configure_event(self, event):
        title = "%s, %s" % (event.x, event.y)
        self.set_title(title)
        Gtk.Window.do_configure_event(self, event)

PyApp()
Gtk.main()
```

I get

> TypeError: argument event: Expected Gdk.EventConfigure, but got gi.overrides.Gdk.Event

from the line with the call to super's do_configure_event. Any idea what I am doing wrong? I am using PyGObject 3.29.2.dev0 and Python 3.7.0.

Comment: You're following an old tutorial for PyGTK (GTK2), but you're using PyGObject (GTK3). You should follow a tutorial like [this](https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for the tools you're using. Don't know if it has a signal override part, but maybe you can check the gnome documentation for that combined with the [PyGObject API documentation](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/)

Comment: The do_configure_event works fine without the override. The problem is that overriding the event changes its type to gi.overrides.Gdk.Event. I have to call the do_configure_event of the superclass or resizing doesn't happen correctly, but that method expects Gdk.EventConfigure. Is there a way to get the original Gdk.EventConfigure back from the gi.overrides.Gdk.Event? Could it be that it is no longer permitted to use do_ methods when overriding a signal (I must use connect instead and return True from the handler to stop emission)? If so, then I am not sure what overriding is for.

Comment: I think I understand a bit more what you're trying to do. I'm not that well versed in gtk3 signals, but, maybe check [this documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/unstable/gobject-Signals.html). There are a couple of functions that may be useful, mainly, `g_signal_override_class_closure`, `g_signal_chain_from_overridden()`, `g_signal_override_class_handler` and `g_signal_chain_from_overridden_handler`. The corresponding functions seem to be available (maybe not all of them) for [PyGObject here](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#GObject-2.0/functions.html#functions). Hope that helps.